# GitLab not 'noticing' file changes after commit

Tags: gitlab

I'm working with GitLab for the past 3 weeks, and now when I commit some changed file, push to the gitlab server and review the commit, it shows that are no alterations to the file, even if I change the whole content. It also shows only the first line of the file, with a strange "B" char in the beginning of the first line (It happens with all files that the problem occurs), like the screenshot below.

[image: GitLab commit]

The GitLab server is in version 8.5.8. (CentOS 7)
I'm using the git client on Windows 8.1 (git 2.7.2)

Has anyone seen this? I can't find anything elsewhere.

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the branch you pushed to?

Comment: @Chris I have only one branch which is 'master'.

Comment: I think something is wrong on the client side, running 'git commit' it already returns "1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)" in the shell, even before pushing to the server.

Comment: If you look at your local commit diffs (e.g. with a graphical tool or `git log --patch` then scrolling with the arrow keys and exiting with `q`) do they match what you are seeing on GitLab?

Comment: Thank you, looking with the graphical tool I found out that git was treating the files as binary, then with some research I realized the files were UTF-16 encoded (the "B" on the first line was the byte order mark from utf16 (þÿ)), I had to open the files with Notepad++ and convert to UTF8, then push them to gitlab, now the changes are showing correctly.